# How do I create a json object that gets appended to the actual response in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I use jSON web tokens (simple-jwt) with my node application. I have a middleware(using express.js) that checks whether the token isValid?() and returns the user data if true.

But when the user does a GET request to localhost:8080/home or any other route, I need it to return the user data(from the tokenValidation middleware) and also the actual contents of localhost:8080/home. I can't use response.json({}) twice since that would be considered as two responses.

What is the standard way to append the user data with the actual json response?

If the code is required, let me know.

Comment: If ``/home`` should return HTML you have to inject user data in it.

Comment: No html gets returned. I am doing api for a mobile app. Hence, all I need is to return json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your middleware you can add a new property to the `req`object.

```
(req, res, next) => {
  const user = ...queryUser
  req.user = user;
  next();
}
```

And in your route handler :

```
(req, res) => {
  const user = req.user;
  const otherData = { data : 'junk' };
  res.status(200).send({ user, otherData });
}
```

Comment: Yes. This works. I thought there might be some other way to automatically append the user_data, without explicitly calling it in each route's expression.

Comment: My understand of node is slim, but I think I just found about res.write().            ie res.send() would end the response and res.write() will keep it open?

Comment: You can create a second middleware that you can apply after your route handlers and call next in your route handlers. And only in this middleware you call res.send()